# How can I solve Vue js router page loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have set up router with vue-cli and it works fine, but the only problem I have is when I click on the new route it doesn't appear on top but only at the bottom or middle of the page.

Comment: Could you maybe post some code for us to look at?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the scrollBehavior when creating a Router.
See the documentation for that: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

The router seems to have some problems when the scrolling is handled by an overflowing div... 
I solved it by adding some JavaScript when using MaterialDesignLite CSS Framework...
[Tap IPhone status bar to scroll to top (mdl + vue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287252/tap-iphone-status-bar-to-scroll-to-top-mdl-vue)